# Rails not loading one of 4 fixtures files correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, fixtures, minitest

I have a strange bug with rails 4 fixtures.

events.yml:

```
work:
  name: "work"
  date_start: 2015-04-21 17:20:18
  date_end: 2015-04-21 18:20:18
  comment: test comment
  admin: egor
  users: [egor]
```

users.yml:

```
egor:
  email: Egor@123.com
  encrypted_password: <%= User.new.send(:password_digest, '12345') %>
  first_name: Egor
```

These yml's works great.
but when i try to load this file

events_users.yml:

```
one:
  user: egor
  event: work
```

I got exception

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'user' in 'field list': INSERT INTO `events_users` (`user`, `event`) VALUES ('egor', 'work')
```

Here is my EventsUsers.rb model ( it is similar to other files )

```
class EventsUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Do you have the migrations in place? Did you run them? Did you run `rake db:test:prepare`?

Comment: Try renaming your model class to EventsUser, the model file to app/models/events_user.rb, and the fixture file to test/fixtures/events_user.yml.

Comment: renaming as suggested in answer make the trick. English is not one of my strong side =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model names should be singular, not plural. So I'm guessing that Rails simply can't find a link between User and EventsUsers (that hurts my head to even type like that). It doesn't know `user` is an object reference because it doesn't recognize "EventsUsers" as a valid model to be associated with a User model.

I'm assuming you are doing a `has_many :through` relationship here? I would suggest making the `:through` option be e.g. "user_event" (and the model named "UserEvent") or, even better, something more descriptive like "outing" (and the model named "Outing"). Try to speak the language that is unique to your domain.

Anyway, once you get the model name back to the conventional, singular form Rails should know how to find it and should be able to make the connection on its own in the fixtures.